# How to unsubscribe from onSnaphot() in mobx-state-tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm using mobx-state-tree's `onSnapshot()` feature to listen to state changes, I then persist the state with every change in local storage. This is how I do it:

```
import { onSnapshot } from "mobx-state-tree";

onSnapshot(store, newSnapshot => {

    saveLocalSnapshot(newSnapshot);

});
```

My question is, how do I unsubscribe from onSnapshot() when my app needs to stop persisting every snapshot?

Comment: As a work-around, I've wrapped the `saveLocalSnapshot()` call in an `if` statement, which checks a new property I added: `store.shouldPersistSnapshots`.  This solves my problem but there has to be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helper functions like `onSpanshot` or `onPatch` (and basically every other subscribe method) return [IDisposer](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/master/docs/API/README.md#idisposer), which is basically a function that you can call to literally dispose the subscription.